# Is there a way to upload an external folder in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a set of custom html pages that are not made with WordPress in folder DIR

In the WordPress blog I have a web page called SPECIAL that only some users can access (after being authenticated). I would like to know if there is a way to allow those users to open the web pages in DIR (in a comfortable way)

For now i am using a very non-pratical solution:
I make a zip archive of that folder, upload it from the Admin interface of WordPress, using WP-Filebase, and put a link to the DIR.zip in the web page SPECIAL.

Yes I agree that my solution is ridiculous. Please help me find a better one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _open the web pages in DIR_?

Comment: @Rahil Wazir In DIR I have normal html static web pages: There is a main index.html with links to other pages. i would like them to be able to view index.html and from it access other pages.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to link to the pages contained within the DIR folder on the SPECIAL page itself, or create an additional WordPress-based page, linked to from SPECIAL, that performs the same function as your DIR/index.html page.

Alternatively you could place an iframe of DIR/index.html on your SPECIAL page.

A longer term solution would be to migrate the contents of DIR into your WordPress installation, and restricting access to the same group of users who can currently see the SPECIAL page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about it but DIR has a huge number of files and i wanted them all to be NOT accessible to someone who has the link unless he is authenticated. Is there a special place where I should put DIR?